# How to use R's read.table with an undefined number of header lines?

Tags: r

I would like to load my file data into a data.frame using the R read.table function. The data is tab delimited with no missing entries. Unfortunately, the number of preamble lines prior to my data will vary. I could quite easily knock together a Java/C/Perl solution; however, I am not so sure in R. The file contents (in a trimmed down mockup) looks like:

```
##header stuff
##header stuff
##header stuff
#column names column names column names
data    data  data   data  data   data
data    data  data   data  data   data
data    data  data   data  data   data
...
data    data  data   data  data   data
```

I would like the read.table to include the line "#column names column names column names" as the column headers to the data.frame.

I could just manually lop the top of the file off and remove the "#" from the headline; however, I plan to make this automated for several hundred files.

**Edit**
The header information in the file can also begin with a @ or an !.

Thanks

Comment: If you always have the same number of header lines that you want to ignore, you could use argument `skip` with `comment.char = ""` to ignore the "header stuff" and still allow parsing the column names.

Comment: Thanks Maurits. Unfortunately, the number of header lines is likely to change per file I run this over.

Comment: I see; in that case perhaps use `readLines` to read the file line-by-line, remove those lines that are "header stuff" based on some regexp maching, and then split lines into column entries using `strsplit`.

Comment: I have used `readLines`, `grep`, and regular expressions to accomplish this in the past. But how you would do this would be specific to your data set.

Comment: There's not yet enough detail in hte question to craft a specific answer. Need to know what idendifies a valid row of column names or what identifies all of the header lines.

Comment: If the comment lines in your files aways begin with #, than `read.table()` will skip those lines by default. I'm assuming that it's not the case, since you posting a question. The solution will involve using `readLines()` to read the file as a text and than `grep` to identify what lines are data, header and comment. Update your question with an example that have the same structure of your data, so we can give you a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks all. I've just been informed by collaborators that header information can also begin with a @ and ! too. Fortunate that you were all able to point me to readLines. I will implement the suggestion below and feedback when I'm in the office. Thanks.

Comment: Since the comment lines can begin with different symbols, use `pattern = '^#|^@|^!'` (and any other symbol you identify in your files) in `grep` when using [Mankind_008 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50980434/9817508) and that should do.

Comment: Thanks @CarlosEduardoLagosta . I updated the answer to avoid any punctuation's all together. Also turned of the default comment character to skip till header row explicilty.

Answer (score 2):

***This should get you going:***

`readLines` *to read line by line.*

`grep` *to find lines starting with* `#` or `@` or`!` or any of the punctuation's `[:punct:]`

`max` *index being the line containing column names and `gsub` to remove the `punctuation's` before splitting into a column character vector*

Also if you are not sure whether lines you need to skip might or might not all contain `#`, which is the defaults *comment character* for *read.table*. It would be better to skip till the non data columns (i.e. `max` which contains header row)

```
log <- readLines("your_file")

column_heading_idx <- max(grep(log, pattern = "^[[:punct:]]"))   # index for header row

col_names <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", log[column_heading_idx])    # removed any punctuation
col_name_vec <- unlist(strsplit(col_names, split = " "))         # split into character vector

read.table("your_file", col.names = col_name_vec, 
           skip = column_heading_idx, comment.char = "")         # turned off character chr 

#   column names column.1 names.1 column.2 names.2
# 1   data  data     data    data     data    data
# 2   data  data     data    data     data    data
# 3   data  data     data    data     data    data
```

***Data Used:***

```
writeLines("your_file", text = "##header stuff
##@header stuff
##@!header stuff
#@column names column names column names
data    data  data   data  data   data
data    data  data   data  data   data
data    data  data   data  data   data")
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped. Exactly what I was after.

Comment: Glad to help. Do post if you got any more concerns/ issues.